Argo workflow SSO RBAC without group scope
I want to use SSO RBAC feature in argo-workflow server where access can be granted on role basis (dev, admin, readonly).
I am referring to link https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/main/docs/argo-server-sso.md. According to doc, if OIDC provider provides the groups only in userInfo then userInfoPath can be used.
I have configured same. it doesn't work for me.
Error: failed to evaluate rule: unknown name groups
My OIDC provider gives below scopes: phone,openid,roles,profile,user_attributes,email It doesn't provide groups as scope
I have used customGroupClaimName as roles , it doesn't work.
Any suggestion?
Thanks.

I found the issue,
userInfoPath was not required since i was able to get the group-roles using customGroupClaimName: roles from my OIDC provider.
Also keeping in mind that filterGroupsRegex filter before rbac rule applies.
